# Rails - determine when a has_many relationship has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I have two models, `Thread` and `Message`. `Thread has many Messages`. In a particular case, I need to update a thread and optionally create a message in the same action... doing so is easy with nested forms.

I need to know mid-request whether or not a message was created and nothing seems to work. I've tried using `counter_cache` with [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), but the value is not recorded in `thread.previous_changes` or `thread.messages_count_changed?`. I've tried removing `counter_cache` on the message and having an `after_create` on message which explicitly updates and saves the number of messages on thread. I've tried using the [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't plug into Message's before_create method to notify the Thread of the creation?

Comment: Thread is a name of Ruby native class, you shouldn't name model like that.

Comment: Just an example name...

Comment: If you are using `accept_nested_attributes_for` with enabled autosave (it is done by default), you can use `thread.changed_for_autosave?`, which check changes in current model and all its nested associations.